# How to fix weird distortion in image from c socket http server with gzip compression and chunked transfer encoding

Tags: c, sockets, gzip, httpserver, chunked

I am currently coding a simple c socket HTTP server that support gzip and chunked transfer.

The snippet for gzip and chunked write to socket is as follows:

```
    // MAXLINE is the buffer size for out and in, which MAXLINE = 1000
    fd = open(filePath, O_RDONLY, 0);

    s.zalloc = s.zfree = s.opaque = NULL;
    deflateInit2(&s, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, 15 | 16, 8, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
    while ((s.avail_in = read(fd, in, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
      s.avail_out = MAXLINE;
      s.next_out = out;
      s.next_in = in;
      deflate(&s, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
      sprintf(header, "%X\r\n", MAXLINE - s.avail_out);
      write(new_socket, header, strlen(header));
      write(new_socket, out, MAXLINE - s.avail_out);
      write(new_socket, "\r\n", 2);
    }
```

The above code works fine, when the requested file is pdf, html, pptx. And they could be downloaded by the browser without any problems or corruption.

However, when I try to request an image, the displayed/ downloaded image are distorted as follows:

Original image:
[image]

Downloaded image:
[image]

I suspects that there are some problems with the code for writing to socket with gzip and chunked transfer, but I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Any idea why this happened? And why it causes problems for images but not other file type such as pdfs?
Any idea how to fix this?
Thank You.

**Update:**

I have tested this using a large text file as suggested by user253751 from the comment, and the downloaded text file has identical content.

So there is no distortion happening to sending a text file with gzip and chunking.

Also, before adding the gzip compression (ie. only chunking), the image was not distorted at all.

So most probably is the gzip compression that causes this problem. But, I'm not sure why and how to fix this.

By comparing both original image and downloaded image using a hex editor, I found out that:

1. There are a lot of bytes missing at the end, as shown in the screen shot below (Left is downloaded, Right is original):

[image]

2. Some row are identical, while some are not.

For example, line with offset 0551980 (first line, 01 44 87 ... DA E0 B4) is identical in both files, but the next line with offset 0552000 (7C 92 77 ... 34 2E 4B; 0C C5 8F ... 1F CD 08) is difference.

I'm not sure how to interpret the result from this comparison, since this is my first time using a hex editor, and also the comparison highlighting was confusing to me.

Since the above difference was not highlighted by wxHexEditor, while in a different line with offset 0552380, only the same C7 was highlighted. So the editor highlights highlights when there is same data? But then why didn't it highlight the first line?

[image]

Moreover, by experimenting with different settings. When modifying the buffer size, the width if the distortion changes, as shown below with MAXLINE = 2000:

[image]

And with MAXLINE = 7000, the distortion disappears, but with a white line at the bottom:

[image]

So it seems that the issue here is probably due to the read buffer loop which probably caused some bytes to be exchanged or omitted?

**Solution:**

Thank You user253751 for figuring out the issue. It turns out that:

> if deflate doesn't read all the input bytes? (if s.avail_in > 0) It just ignores the bytes it didn't read, and overwrites them with the next bytes in the file! So those bytes never get compressed and sent!

So, to mitigate this problem, a loop needs to surround deflate() and check whether the available out buffer(s.avail_out) is empty or not. If s.avail_out == 0 after deflate, that means compression used up all the spaces of out buffer, and we need to recall deflate() to deal with the bytes it didn't read/compressed.

Or checking for s.avail_in != 0 for the while loop.

The working code is as follows:

```
    // MAXLINE is the buffer size for out and in, which MAXLINE = 1000
    fd = open(filePath, O_RDONLY, 0);

    s.zalloc = s.zfree = s.opaque = NULL;
    deflateInit2(&s, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, 15 | 16, 8, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
    while ((s.avail_in = read(fd, in, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
      s.next_in = in;
      do {
        s.avail_out = MAXLINE;
        s.next_out = out;
        deflate(&s, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
        sprintf(header, "%X\r\n", MAXLINE - s.avail_out);
        write(new_socket, header, strlen(header));
        write(new_socket, out, MAXLINE - s.avail_out);
        write(new_socket, "\r\n", 2);
      //} while (s.avail_out == 0);
      } while (s.avail_in != 0);
    }
```

Comment: Can you try transferring a large text file so that we can see what your program is doing to the *bytes* in the file? It is hard to tell based on the image. With a text file, it is much easier to see how your program is affecting the file data, because missing or duplicate text is easier to spot.

Comment: (also is this picture Berlin's Oberbaumbrücke viewed from the northeast?)

Comment: I have tried sending large text file, but the downloaded content is the same, so no distortion. And yes, the picture is Berlin's Oberbaumbrücke, but I'm forgot which direction I took it.

Comment: Obviously the downloaded content is not the same. If it works on text files but not JPEGs, my next suggestion is to open the original JPEG and the downloaded JPEG in a hex editor, and try to spot the differences (or let your hex editor find the differences if it has that feature).

Comment: I have found out that for the downloaded file, there is a lot of bytes missing at the end of the file as shown above. So it seems that the code did not compress/ transfer the  bytes at the end.

Comment: If you look at the bytes *before* the end, they are not the same bytes. So, I suspect that your program is not sending some bytes in the *middle*, so the end doesn't line up, but the end is not the problem. See that the line at offset 0551980 is the same but starting from 0552000 it's completely different.

Comment: Hey I think I noticed the problem. What does your program do if `deflate` doesn't read all the input bytes? (if s.avail_in > 0) It just ignores the bytes it didn't read, and overwrites them with the next bytes in the file! So those bytes never get compressed and sent!

Comment: Yes you are right, when the compression output requires more than the buffer size, then the code would just ignores the bytes it didn't read. Fixed it by adding a loop to check for s.avail_out == 0 to surround deflate(). Thank You. :)

Comment: Great! Now I've posted that as an answer. I'd recommend checking for `s.avail_in != 0` instead of `s.avail_out == 0` - just in case the compressor decides to read half the data but not output any! (It *says* that it keeps going until the input is empty or the output is full... but maybe another version in 10 years won't do that... do you want to risk it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deflate` reads some uncompressed bytes from the in buffer and writes some compressed bytes to the out buffer. Your code is careful to send all the compressed bytes down the socket, even if the socket doesn't send them all at once. But your code is *not* careful with the uncompressed bytes!

If `deflate` fills up the output buffer first, then there are still input bytes left over when it returns. Your code ignores those leftover input bytes and instead of trying to compress them again, it overwrites them with the next bytes from the file.

The reason you see this with JPEG files but not with text files is that JPEG files are already compressed, so they can't be compressed any more. That means the gzipped JPEG output is *bigger* than the original JPEG, so the output buffer fills up before the input buffer is empty. With the text file, it compresses well and there is plenty of room in the output buffer.